# How can i change css transitions for different actions?

Tags: css

i have this code

http://jsfiddle.net/d2QwG/

When user hover on image after 1 sec the others change `opacity:0.4`.
But when the user goes to another image i want all the images to return to `opacity:1`and if he again hover over a sec the others to change `opacity:0.4`.

I understand that the rule

```
#tiles li {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
     -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
       -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
          transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}
```

makes the problem but i want to keep this rule for another transition that i make when some `<li>` items are moving.

I want the visual result like i didnt have the above CSS rule but without deleting it.

I dont mind using javascipt,jquery.

EDIT:
I want this result:
http://jsfiddle.net/KJ8T4/
but i want also to have this CSS rule

```
#tiles li {
      -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
         -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
           -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
              transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could to use JavaScript or jQuery for that.

Here's a <kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d2QwG/1/)</kbd>.

```
$('li').on("mouseout", function() {
   $('img').css('opacity', '1');
});
```

Comment: Nothing changed here from my code. I have the same result with or without your code. Try move from an image to another horizontally to see what i mean.

Comment: Did you look at the Fiddle I gave you? It does exactly what you are asking. All start out with opacity=1, once you stay 1 second over an image, the rest turn to opacity=.4, once you move to another image and wait for 1 sec, that image turns to opacity=1, and everything else goes to opacity=.4. So which part am I missing exactly?

Comment: OK, I think I get it. It's the transition delay, right? So when you move from one image to another image, you want the opacity to change immediately?

Comment: Exactly man. When i move from an image to another i want all the images to return to opacity=1 immediately and then if i stay to an image over 1 sec the others to turn to opacity=0.4 and so on. I want the same result as user hover outside <ul id="tiles">

Answer (score 0):

Pure CSS solution:

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/UrUxOwor/1/edit)

```
#tiles{
  margin:0;
  list-style:none;
  display:table;
  border-collapse:collapse;
}    
#tiles li {
  vertical-align:middle;
  display:table-cell;
  padding:5px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}
#tiles li img{
  vertical-align:middle;
}    
#tiles:hover li{
  opacity: 0.4;
}
#tiles li:hover{
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: That code doesnt seem to solve my problem becouse you havent add the delay option. I want all the other images to change opacity after the user is hovering over an image more tha 1 second. I want the transition-delay: 1s; to be added